# Find the derivative of $y=(2x-1)^{10}(x-1)^3$

Tags: calculus

**Edit: Got it**

Find the derivative of $y=(2x-1)^{10}(x-1)^3$

Solution:

Applying the product and chain rule I have:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=\dfrac{d}{dx}(2x-1)^{10}(x-1)^3+(2x-1)^{10}\dfrac{d}{dx}(x-1)^3\\
&=10(2x-1)^9)(x-1)^3+(2x-1)^{10}(3)(x-1)^2\\
&=10(2x-1)^9(2)(x-1)^3+(2x-1)^{10}(3)(x-1)\\
&=20(2x-1)^9(x-1)^3+3(2x-1)^{10}(x-1)\\
&=(2x-1)^9(x-1)^2\bigg(20(x-1)+3(2x-1)\bigg)\\
&=\boxed{(2x-1)^9(x-1)^2\bigg(26x-23\bigg)}
\end{align*}

Thanks

Comment: $\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=(x-1)^3\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(2x-1)^{10}+(2x-1)^{10}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(x-1)^3 \\
 &= (x-1)^3\cdot10(2x-1)^9\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(2x-1) +(2x-1)^{10}\cdot3(x-1)^2\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(x-1)\\
&= ?
\end{align*}$

Comment: after the product rule, take the derivatives of $(2x-1)$ and $(x-1)$. (@ 3rd line of your equation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=(x-1)^3\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(2x-1)^{10}+(2x-1)^{10}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(x-1)^3 \\
&=(x-1)^3\cdot10\cdot\color{red}2(2x-1)^9+(2x-1)^{10}\cdot3\cdot\color{red}1(x-1)^2\\
\end{align*}

You just multiply by the derivative of the expressions.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem, forgot that.